# Running a node file, via a .sh from .php on linux

Tags: php, linux, node.js

I'm trying to run a node file from php.  The following works...

running the node from terminal
running an .sh that runs the node file from terminal
running a .sh from php, that writes a text file ( so the php is succesfully triggering the .sh )

However, when I run the .sh file, running the node file from php it fails.  I have tried using wait 30 ( the process takes about 10 seconds ) to make sure it's not exiting before completion. Do I need to set any special permissions in order for php --> .sh --> node to work?  Done quite a bit of searching can't find anything.

Comment: Can you show us the simplest set of code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a dreaded permission problem. Does the owner of the Apache instance have the same rights to execute `node filename.js` as you when you're in the terminal? Try doing `su *apache_user*` and then attempting to run the file. Does it work that way from the terminal?

Comment: Sure...

php...
shell_exec( 'sh t.sh' );

.sh...

#!/bin/bash
sudo node nodeWriteFile.js
echo 'non node works from here' >thisAlwaysWorksFromPhp.txt

node...

var fs = require( 'fs-extra' )
fs.writeFile( "butThisNeverWorksFromPhp.txt", "", 'utf8', function( err ) {
 if ( err ) {
  throw err;
 } 
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand how the file and execution chain is completed in order to understand why this won't work (assumedly).

*Assuming a pretty common setup below...*

When Apache is initialized, it has an owner, we'll say `www-data` in this particular case. Now, Apache will execute and listen on port 80 as the `www-data` user. This means that all requests it handles from here on out will be executed as the `www-data` user.

So when you go to http://example.com/my-page.php, Apache is going to receive this request. Then it's going to go out and find the file associated with `my-page.php` in the file system based on it's `DocumentRoot` in the `VirtualHost` directive. Once it's done this, the PHP interpreter that has been attached to the `.php` file will do a top down interpretation of the file.

Once it gets to your bash script, `www-data` is still the owner. Now the `bash script` has been executed as `www-data` in this case, and I'm willing to bet that `www-data` (or your Apache user) is not in the list of **sudoers** (and rightfully so).

To combat this problem, you should instead make sure that the `node` instance can be invoked without sudo permissions on your paritcular configuration. If this is just a localhost thing and the outside world isn't going to be hitting it, I'd say adding `www-data` (or your Apache user) to the list of **sudoers** wouldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, Im going to take time out to get up to speed with permissions